# Are javascript <script> tags efficient when parsing through Handlebars data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm essentially selecting * from my database in my backend server.js, and passing it along to a handlebars file that attempts to parse the data into a table. The hbs file looks like this below:

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>username</th>
                <th>password (encrypted)</th>
                <th>write privileges</th>
                <th>admin privileges</th>
                <th>modify</th>
                <th>delete</th>
            </tr>
            {{#each user}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ this.user }}</td>
                <td>{{ this.password }}</td>
                <td><script type="text/javascript"> if ({{ this.p_write }} == 1) { document.write('<i class="ti ti-check safe"></i>'); }</script></td>
                <td><script type="text/javascript"> if ({{ this.p_admin }} == 1) { document.write('<i class="ti ti-check safe"></i>'); }</script></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="warning"><i class="ti ti-edit"></i></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="danger"><i class="ti ti-circle-minus"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
            {{/each  }}
        </table>
```

The output of the above code can also be seen below:

[image: Table output]

I'm wondering whether the `<script>` tags I'm using to check the values of `this.p_admin` and `this.p_write` (to decide whether or not to write the green checkmarks) are particularly efficient, and if there's a better way to do this in my situation. I'm fairly new at this, so there might be an obvious solution that's not coming to me. Thanks.

Comment: The use of `document.write()` is "strongly discouraged". See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write. You should be able to achieve your goal purely in Handlebars. For example: `{{#if this.p_write}}<i class="ti ti-check safe"></i>{{/if}}`

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in the comments, use Handlebars `if` conditions rather than `document.write`. Not only is [`document.write()` strongly discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), it also pushes server-side work to the client, meaning the data will be injected dynamically with JS rather than baked into the HTML. This impacts usability by adding a brief delay before the content is visible and harms SEO.

Here's a runnable example you can adapt to your use case (the `<table>` is the relevant part--everything else is there just so you can interact with it as a stack snippet in the browser):

```js
// example boilerplate for the purposes of the snippet
const users = [
  {user: "foo", password: "bar", p_write: false, p_admin: true},
  {user: "baz", password: "baz", p_write: true, p_admin: false},
  {user: "quux", password: "quux", p_write: false, p_admin: true},
];
const html = document.querySelector("#template").innerHTML;
const template = Handlebars.compile(html);
document.body.innerHTML = template({users});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>username</th>
      <th>password (encrypted)</th>
      <th>write privileges</th>
      <th>admin privileges</th>
      <th>modify</th>
      <th>delete</th>
    </tr>
    {{#each users}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{user}}</td>
      <td>{{password}}</td>
      <td>
        {{#if p_write}}
          <i class="ti ti-check safe">test</i>
        {{/if}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{#if p_admin}}
          <i class="ti ti-check safe">test</i>
        {{/if}}
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="warning">
          <i class="ti ti-edit">test</i>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="danger">
          <i class="ti ti-circle-minus">test</i>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@4.7.8/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
```